# MailMerge query string exceeds 255 characters

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm having an issue with my automated mailmerge application.  The application uses an MS Word template and an MS Word datasource. I'm using the following method to create the datasource and bind it to the template:

```
 expression.CreateDataSource(Name, PasswordDocument, WritePasswordDocument, HeaderRecord, MSQuery, SQLStatement, SQLStatement1, Connection, LinkToSource);
```

Here is the MSDN page on this method, for reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820730(v=office.15).aspx

Everything works fine, however, some of my Word templates have many if statements, making the query string longer than 255 characters.  When the application tries to execute the createDataSource method, it errors out.

It looks like the MSDN page says the SQLStatement, SQLStatement1 parameters can be used to break up the query into two portions.  So, my question is how do utilize these parameters??  They are optional, and currently I am not using them.

Maybe there is even a better solution to this?  Any insight would be great!  I've done a lot web searching and haven't found a clear solution.

Please let me know if any additional info. is needed to better solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Word executes the OpenDataSource method, it concatenates the SQLStatement and SQLStatement1 parameter values to create a single query statement. To use a simplified example, if your query needs to be

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

Then you could for example set

```
SQLStatement:="SELECT *", SQLStatement1:=" FROM mytable"
```

i.e. you need to ensure that significant spaces are in the concatenated string.

The limit on the total query length may vary depending on the data source. AFAICR some source types/connection methods still had a limit of 255 characters. But I think you'll get the full 511 that Word allows with a .mdb/.accdb source.

The other way to do it with a data source that supports queries/views may be to create a query or view within the database and use that as the data source instead.

Comment: thanks for your response!  I may not be understanding my issue entirely.  When my app executes the Mailmerge.CreateDataSource method, it then gives me the character limit error.  The only parameters I set for this are the source path and the headers list, the values are filled in afterwards. Also I don't currently set the sqlstatement parameters manually. Is the error happening because I have too many different values in the headers list?

Comment: My bad, really. AFAIK, CreateDataSource only lets you create flat data files (e.g. .docx format in newer versions of Windows Word). The character limit error to do with a string length limit in some Word parameters. The fact that your query criteria result in a long query is probably not the source of the problem. FWIW with CreateDataSource you could use shorter field names to have more fields (up to  ~64 fields if Word creates a .docx data source). For a more flexible data source, try using ADO and/or ADOX to create a .mdb/.accdb instead, then connect using OpenDataSource.